# how to generate blank table rows before filling with ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am relatively new to JavaScript

```js
angular
    .module('MainView', ['Utils','ngMaterial'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','$timeout','$q','$log' ,function($scope,$timeout,$q,$log) {
        var self = this;
        self.keychain = null;

 self.keychain = [{description:'some description',couponCode:37678 },{description:'some text',couponCode:23478,unitPrice:300.99,totalCost:300.99,actions: 'move' }]

    }]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="MainView" ng-controller="MainCtrl">                
<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Coupon Code</th>
  
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.stockList track by $index" class="item--{{$index}}">
                            <td>{{$index + 1}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="mdl-textfield__input">
                                <input value="{{item.qty}}" size="3" maxlength="3" class="" type="number"  required />
                            </td>
                            <td>{{item.couponCode || 'n/a'}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.description || 'n/a'}}</td>
                          <td>            <button  class="mdl-button mdl-js-button ">
                            <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                            </button></td>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
  </div>
```

and angular. I am trying to get a blank scroll-able table which i can then enter data into.How can i do this using ng-repeat.I have been on this for several hours. Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your stocklist with empty values

```
vm.stockList = [
    {qty: null, couponCode: null, description: null},
    {qty: null, couponCode: null, description: null},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not run your code snippet and you are using stockList <--!--> keychain.

So the first thing i see is that your input uses value="{{item.qty}}" whereas you should use ng-model="item.qty"

see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Answer (score 0):

Here it's working. You missed out angular file. And so many unwanted codes.

```js
angular.module('MainView', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope' ,function($scope) {
        var self = this;
        self.keychain = null;
  self.keychain = [{description:'some description', couponCode:37678 }, 
                  {description:'some text',couponCode:23478,unitPrice:300.99,totalCost:300.99,actions: 'move' }];
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MainView">                
<table ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Coupon Code</th>
  
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in vm.keychain" class="item">
                            <td>{{$index + 1}}
                            </td>
                            <td class="mdl-textfield__input">
                                <input size="3" maxlength="3" class="" type="number"  required />
                            </td>
                            <td>{{item.couponCode}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                          <td>            <button  class="mdl-button mdl-js-button ">
                            <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                            </button></td>


                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
  </div>
```